# Migrate data from old table to new table query

Tags: php, mysql, sql

Need a little help creating a query that takes the `topic_title`, and `topic_content` from `mb_topics`, and the `post_content` from the `mb_posts` table and then inserts the `mb_topics.topic_title` into the `forum_topics.topic_title` (table.field), `mb_topics.topic_content` and `mb_posts.post_content` into the `forum_posts` table.

Is it possible to use a single select query?

`mb` tables:

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `mb_posts` (
  `id` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `posted_by` bigint(20) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
  `topic_id` int(11) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
  `post_content` text NOT NULL
) ENGINE=MyISAM DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;

CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `mb_topics` (
  `id` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `topic_title` varchar(75) NOT NULL DEFAULT '',
  `posted_by` bigint(20) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
  `topic_content` text NOT NULL
) ENGINE=MyISAM DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;
```

`forum` tables:

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `forum_posts` (
  `post_id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `post_content` text NOT NULL,
  `post_date` datetime NOT NULL,
  `post_topic` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `post_by` int(11) unsigned NOT NULL
  PRIMARY KEY (`post_id`),
  KEY `post_topic` (`post_topic`),
  KEY `post_by` (`post_by`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB  DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8 AUTO_INCREMENT=1 ;

CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `forum_topics` (
  `topic_id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `topic_title` varchar(150) NOT NULL,
  `topic_by` int(11) unsigned NOT NULL
  PRIMARY KEY (`topic_id`),
  KEY `topic_by` (`topic_by`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB  DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8 AUTO_INCREMENT=1 ;
```

PHP:

```
$get_old_data_query=mysql_query('SELECT `title`, `content` FROM `mb_topics`');
while($old_data=mysql_fetch_assoc($get_old_data_query))
{
    $old_data_array[]=$old_data;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Something like this i guess would be ok?

```
<?php
$Old = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM Table WHERE Name = 'Name'");

while(mysql_fetch_array($Old)){
$Data = mysql_fetch_array($Old);
$Old1 = $Data['Name'];

mysql_query("INSERT INTO NewTable (Name) VALUES ('$Old1')");
}
```

Comment: `$old1` is not the same as `$Old1`. Those are two different animals altogether and will throw an undefined variable Old1 notice.

Comment: You're welcome Kristian. Now to see what the OP has to say ;-) cheers

Comment: Yeah, this is pretty much how I decided to do it.

Answer (score 0):

This following query will fetch data from *mb_posts* and *mb_topics* tables and will insert into *forum_posts* table.

```
INSERT INTO forum_posts( post_content, post_topic, post_date, post_by ) 
SELECT MBP.post_content, MBT.id, NOW( ) , MBP.posted_by
FROM mb_posts AS MBP
LEFT JOIN mb_topics AS MBT ON MBP.topic_id = MBT.id
```

Similarly the following query will get post topics from old table (mb_topics) to new table (forum_topics).

```
INSERT INTO forum_topics( topic_title, topic_by) 
SELECT MBT.topic_title, MBT.posted_by
FROM mb_posts AS MBP
LEFT JOIN mb_topics AS MBT ON MBP.topic_id = MBT.id
```

Answer (score -1):

This would be 2 separate queries, because with one INSERT you can only insert into 1 table.